# AngularJS: Sorting of ng-repeat table which contains function

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

In this code i am trying to sort data in particular column by clicking on table header. It works fine till end date of course after that sorting doesnt work. It dont work on column no of days & no of days remaining. Anyone have any solution?

```
                var app= angular.module("myapp",[]);
                app.controller("mycontroller",function ($scope, $http)

                    {

                        //subtraction between dates
                        $scope.CurrentDate=new Date();
                        $scope.calDate = function(date1, date2){
                           var dateOut1 = new Date(date1);
                           var dateOut2 = new Date(date2);
                           var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOut2.getTime() - dateOut1.getTime());

                           var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
                           return diffDays;
                        };
                        $scope.getToday = function(){
                            return new Date();
                        }

                    });    

</script>
<body ng-app ="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <table border=1>
                <tr>

                    <th ng-click="sortData('name')">Name of student <div ng-class="getSortClass('name')"></div></th>
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .
                    <th ng-click="sortData('edate')">End date of course <div ng-class="getSortClass('edate')" ></th>
                    <th> No of days </th>  //sorting is not working on this column
                    <th>No of Days remaining </th> //sorting is not working on this column

                </tr>
                    <tr   ng-repeat="x in names  | filter: searchText | orderBy:sortColumn:reverSort">

                        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.cname}}</td>
                        <td >{{x.cfees}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.fpaid }}</td>
                        <td>{{x.bfees}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.sdate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.edate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                        <td>{{calDate(x.edate,x.sdate)}}</td>
                        <td>{{calDate(x.edate,getToday()| date:'dd-MM-yyyy')}}</td>                     
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`calDate` is a function and it is not part of your ng-repeat data. Try to add it to the names collection as below.

```
 $scope.names = <your code to populate names>;

    angular.forEach($scope.names, function(name){
          name.NoOfDays = $scope.calDate(name.edate, name.sdate);
          name.DaysRemaining = $scope.calDate(name.edate, $scope.gettoday());
   });
```

Then you can bind it in HTML as below.

```
<td>{{x.NoOfDays}}</td>
<td>{{x.DaysRemaining| date:'dd-MM-yyyy')}}</td>
```

Comment: I applied this code but that No Of days columns bcomes empty. No data is passing to that column. I am fetching data from mySQL with PHP

Comment: Above code is just an approach. You need to apply it on the right place.  NoOfDays is showing empty because the data binding happens before you manipulate the data for NoOfDays and DaysRemaining. After getting result from mySQL do not assign it to $scope.names. Instead do the data manipulation using angular.forEach and then assign the data to $scope.names. Hope this helps